# Python Tensorflow ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow. I tried to put tensor list into the `tf.train.batch()` function, but I got an `ValueError (too many values to unpack (expected 2))`. Here is my code, and the error is from the second line.

```
g = tf.unstack(data, num = 60366, axis = 0)
X_mb, _ = tf.train.batch(g, 32, capacity = 60366)
```

My data is a [60366, 39] matrix.

Can someone help me?
Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need this:

```
X_mb, *_ = tf.train.batch(g, 32, capacity = 60366)
```

or this:

```
X_mb = tf.train.batch(g, 32, capacity = 60366)[0]
```